Using Aws Lex V2 with Aws Connect for a self-managed voicebot and chatbot
there,
I have configured an Amazon Lex V2 bot with different intents and I would like to have a voicebot and chatbot that can be used with Amazon Connect. I have tried different solutions by testing with Connect Test Chat and none of them work:

Option 1: Use a Get User Input in a flow to access my Lex bot. The problems I'm having are as follows: I have to use the Text-to-speech or chat text with a start phrase to access Lex. Once that's done, I can send a message which is relayed to Lex, and the bot responds as long as it stays within the intention detected with my first sentence. But as soon as the Lex bot needs to change its intent (either via a delegate or an elicitIntent, actions specific to Lex), the flow with Lex stops and I exit the Get User Input. What's more, even if I add a Loop or another element, I can't continue the conversation because the Initialize bot with message option in the Get User Input stops the conversation and triggers an error. I've seen something about InitialMessage which would have been configured recently but I haven't managed to implement it.

Option 2: Use a lambda directly invoked in an Aws Connect flow. The problem I'm having is that I can't manage to save the user input so that I can send it to the lambda which will call Lex directly. I manage to call Lex but I can't save the user input sent in the chat. I've used a Wait to give me time to enter the message but then the message isn't present in the event sent to the lambda.


Neither of these options works for me.
Please help me if you know more or if you know of another option that would allow me to use Aws Lex V2 to reply on Aws Connect.
Thanks in advance,
Elise

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
